# Using Count method on a for loop in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The issue I am having is that I am trying to generate a series of text boxes using a for loop to prevent verbose code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.frames(); i++)
       {
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-1 text-left ">
            frame Number
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
               @Model.frames
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        }
```

The "count" is not recognized for Integer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of `Model.frames` ?

Comment: What is property `frames`? (is it `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is an integer

Comment: Then its `for (int i = 0; i < Model.frames; i++)`, but your `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.frames)` code then makes no sense. And neither does `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` - you not generating a form or form controls for `frames`

Comment: Why are you calling Count method on an integer value ? Ex : `100.Count()` ! what is your expected behavior  with this expression? You should call Count on a collection (Ex : List of integers)

Comment: The intended behavior is to output a series of text boxes, in this case 10. Which will receive a variable from elsewhere on the page.

Comment: I have edited the block of code to remove the issues explained in the comments, I am now receiving a different error "non-invocable member being used like a method"

Comment: Is `frames()` a method in your view model which returns a number ? If not your code is wrong!

Comment: @Shyju Thank you very much, I had missed deleting that. That resolved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, `int` primitive value doesn't have `Count` method, it works with `IEnumerable` objects (`List`, `Dictionary` etc). You need to pass `frames` as collection on view then `Model.frames.Count` may be used.